# Downloading file via hidden iframe - how to tell if download completes/fails/is aborted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, download

When a user clicks my download link there is a slight pause between the click and when the download dialog pops up in the users browser, this is because my server is creating a zip of a bunch of files and it could take a short while.

So, I want to place a loading spinner and disable the link during this time to prevent the user hammering the download link again. Only problem is I need to re-enable the link and hide the spinner, but Im not sure how I can tell when the download popup appears.

Im using a hidden iframe to trigger the download and the onload/onsubmit events seem to fire *before* the popup is shown, i.e. when the iframes src attribute is set or when the iframes is added to the dom.

Any ideas how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

return a string based on the serverside of the iframed page of an "ok" or "error" string.

Check the iFrame for changes:

```
$("iframe#uploadProcessor").load(function(){
       if($(this).text().indexOf("Error") > -1){
          console.log($(this).html());
       }else{
          var wrapper = $("div#main div#closets.tabContent div#UploadFormWrapper");
           if(wrapper.hasClass('Active')){
                  wrapper.animate({"height":"0px"}, {"queue": false, "duration": 400}).fadeOut(375, function(){
                           wrapper.removeClass('Active');
                          });
                    }
                           require(["AJAX"], function(AJAX){
                               AJAX.ajaxUpdateCloset($("form#UploadForm select#OutfitCloset")[0].value);
                           });
                       }
                       $("div#main div#closets.tabContent form#UploadForm")[0].reset();
                   });
```